# Load XML data with Python

Tags: python, xml

I have this code that is working, but how can I load item value instead of object itself and record it into array.

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
tree = xml.parse(urllib.urlopen('http://lazhalazha.livejournal.com/data/rss'))
rootElement = tree.getroot()
for a in rootElement.findall('channel/item/guid'):
    print a
```

Outputs

```
<Element 'guid' at 0xb75316ec>
<Element 'guid' at 0xb7531a0c>
<Element 'guid' at 0xb7531c8c>
<Element 'guid' at 0xb7531f0c>
<Element 'guid' at 0xb753a22c>
<Element 'guid' at 0xb753a4ec>
<Element 'guid' at 0xb753a7ac>
<Element 'guid' at 0xb753aa6c>
<Element 'guid' at 0xb753ad2c>
```

Comment: `urllib` is unnecessary. `xml.parse(theurl)` will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want `a.text`?

If the `guid` element may contain child elements with their own text and you want the text serialization of the whole thing, use `etree.tostring(a, method='text')`.

This is a very basic question. Read through the [`lxml` tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class) on the `Element` class.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the attribute text:
http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text)
and the method find text:
http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext

But if you want to parse RSS, you should definitely consider using feedparser: http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/